# Integral with 4 radicals-hat

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'd like to find out a simple way for calculating the value of:

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1 + {\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{x}}}}}\,dx .$$

Of course, I thought of some variable change, but it seems pretty complicated. 
On the other hand, I wonder if there can be made a generalization when having 
to deal with the expression with $k$ radicals, $k>1$.

Comment: as $k \to \infty$ it seems like the integral goes to $\phi$

Comment: surprisingly, this is Wolfram integrable.

Comment: Nothing surprising - just substitute $t=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}}$.

Comment: (with 3 ones) After that substitution, Maple gets $$\frac{16 t^{17}}{17} - \frac{112 t^{15}}{15} + \frac{288 t^{13}}{13} - \frac{320 t^{11}}{11} + \frac{112 t^{9}}{9} + \frac{48 t^{7}}{7} - \frac{32 t^{5}}{5}$$

Comment: @ GEdgar: i suppose that things get worse when dealing with more radicals in place.

Comment: @picakhu It *does* converges to $\phi$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$. It is not hard to prove it since $\phi = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}$ and the integral is from $0$ to $1$ and the integrand can be bound between $\phi - \epsilon(k)$ and $\phi + \epsilon(k)$ for a given $k$ and $\epsilon(k) \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: And the definite integral is $-{\frac {26704}{765765}}\,\sqrt {1+\sqrt {1+\sqrt {2}}}\sqrt {1+\sqrt 
{2}}\sqrt {2}+{\frac {83584}{765765}}\,\sqrt {1+\sqrt {1+\sqrt {2}}}
\sqrt {1+\sqrt {2}}-{\frac {17168}{765765}}\,\sqrt {1+\sqrt {1+\sqrt {
2}}}\sqrt {2}+{\frac {344096}{765765}}\,\sqrt {1+\sqrt {1+\sqrt {2}}}-
{\frac {256}{3003}}\,\sqrt {1+\sqrt {2}}\sqrt {2}+{\frac {67328}{
109395}}\,\sqrt {1+\sqrt {2}}
$

Comment: @Robert Israel: how did you get this result?

Comment: Using the Maple commands:

> f:=sqrt(1+sqrt(1+sqrt(1+sqrt(x))));

> j:= int(f,x=0..1);

> IntegrationTools[Change](j,t=f);

> simplify(%,radical);

Comment: @Robert Israel: OK. Maybe things would work better with some trigonometric substitution. In any case, it doesn't seem an easy case, at all.

Comment: @Chris: The answer is what it is.  I don't know what "better" result you expect to get with a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: My answer was for infinite radicals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Let
   $$\begin{eqnarray*}
   u &=&\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}} \Leftrightarrow &x=\left( \left( u^{2}-1\right) ^{2}-1\right)
   ^{2}=u^{8}-4u^{6}+4u^{4}.
   \end{eqnarray*}$$
   Since $$\begin{equation*}
   dx=\left( 8u^{7}-24u^{5}+16u^{3}\right) du
   \end{equation*}$$ we have 
   $$I :=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}}dx\\=\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}\sqrt{1+u}\left(8u^{7}-24u^{5}+16u^{3}\right) du.\quad\textit{(computation below)}^†
   $$ Each term can be integrated using the substitution $t=\sqrt{1+u}$ $$\begin{equation*}
   \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+u}u^{n}du=2\int_{\sqrt{1+a}}^{\sqrt{1+b}}t^{2}\left(
   t^{2}-1\right) ^{n}\,dt,\quad a=\sqrt{2},b=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}.
   \end{equation*}$$
2. *Generalization to $k=5$ radicals* $$\begin{equation*}
   J:=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}}}dx.
   \end{equation*}$$ Similarly to above the substitution is now
   $$\begin{eqnarray*} v &=&\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}}\Leftrightarrow  x=\left( \left( \left( v^{2}-1\right) ^{2}-1\right) ^{2}-1\right) ^{2} \\  x &=& v^{16}-8v^{14}+24v^{12}-32v^{10}+14v^{8}+8v^{6}-8v^{4}-1,
   \end{eqnarray*}$$ and
   $$\begin{equation*} dx=\left(
   16v^{15}-112v^{13}+288v^{11}-320v^{9}+112v^{7}+48v^{5}-32v^{3}\right) dv.
   \end{equation*}$$

Hence
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
J &=&\int_{\alpha }^{\beta }\sqrt{1+v}\left(
16v^{15}-112v^{13}+288v^{11}-320v^{9}+112v^{7}+48v^{5}-32v^{3}\right) dv \\
\alpha  &=&\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}},\beta =\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

--

†*In SWP I obtained*

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&-\frac{26\,704}{765\,765}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}
\sqrt{2} \\&&+\frac{83\,584}{765\,765}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1} \\
&&+\frac{344\,096}{765\,765}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}} \\
&&+\frac{67\,328}{109\,395}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1} \\
&&-\frac{256}{3003}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\sqrt{2} \\
&&-\frac{17\,168}{765\,765}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}\sqrt{2} \\
&\approx &1.584\,9.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

1) First substitute $$\,t=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}\Longrightarrow dt=\frac{dx}{4\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}\Longrightarrow dx=4(t^2-1)tdt$$ , and now change the limits to $\,1\,,\,\sqrt{2}$

2) Next, you have $$4\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\,t(t^2-1)\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+t}}\,dt$$ , and now substitute $$y=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+t}}$$and etc. You end up with a not-so-terrible polynomial function.